# SQL server duplicate records issue

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

I have two source tables `CustP` and `CustS` (this table is only to store email id, this is how current design is)

**CustP**:

```
CustID  Fname      Lname        Phone
------------------------------------------
100     John        Doe         1234567890
200     John        Doe         1234567890
300     John        Doe         NULL
```

**CustS**:

```
CustID  Fname       Lname       Email
--------------------------------------------
100     John        Doe         NULL
200     John        Doe         a@a.com   
300     John        Doe         a@a.com
```

I would like to identify duplicate records from above 2 tables based on below criteria :

- if (FName, Lname and phone matches) OR (FName, Lname and email matches)

Below are the steps I am using to generate the duplicate result set

```
drop table #AllCustomer

select 
    cp.CustID, cp.Fname, cp.Lname, cp.Phone, cs.Email,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by cp.Fname) RN
into 
    #AllCustomer
from 
    CustP cp
inner join 
    CustS cs on cp.CustID = cs.CustID

 --Combining the customer and matched customer into a temp table
 Select   
     A.CustID CustID, B.CustID MatchedCustID,
     A.Fname FirstName,
     A.Lname SurName,
     A.Phone Phone,
     A.Email Email,
     B.Fname MatchedFirstName,
     B.Lname MatchedSurName,
     B.Phone MatchedPhone,
     B.Email MatchedEmail           
 into 
     #AllMatchedCustomers
 from 
     #AllCustomer A
 inner join
     #AllCustomer B on (A.Fname = B.Fname
                        and A.Lname = B.Lname
                        and A.CustID <> B.CustID
                        and A.RN < B.RN)
 where 
     A.CustID <> B.CustID
     and (((1 = case  
                   when isnull(A.Phone, 1) in (isnull(B.Phone, 2))
                      then 1
                      else 0
                end))
           or
           (A.Fname = B.Fname and A.Lname = B.Lname and 
            isnull(A.Email, 'A') = isnull(B.Email, 'B'))
          )
```

And the result is as shown below

```
CustID  MatchedCustID   FirstName   SurName Phone   Email   MatchedFirstName    MatchedSurName  MatchedPhone    MatchedEmail
100 200 John        Doe         1234567890  NULL    John        Doe         1234567890  a@a.com   
200 300 John        Doe         1234567890  a@a.com     John        Doe         NULL    a@a.com
```

I need help in identifying if Cust100 is matched with Cust200 with phone number and cust200 Is related to cust300 via email , then result should include one more additional row showing Cust100 and cust300(because a=b, b=c therefore a=c). (here it would be 100 and 300 in the 3rd row of result set).  Or what are the alternative approaches? Appreciate your help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we use values in `CustID` column to join two tables together? Do  these values match, or they are independent IDs?

Comment: custid in CustP and Custs matches (Fkey relation ship), and we can join using custid, thank you

Comment: Do each table individualy and them check the results of each table against the other.